# open() not setting file permissions correctly

Tags: c, posix

I create a file using the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    const char* filename = "./test.out";
    int fd;
    if(-1 == (fd = open(filename, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0666)))
    {
        perror("Error");
        errno = 0;
    }       
    else
        puts("File opened");

    if(-1 == (close(fd)))
    {
        perror("Error");
        errno = 0;
    }
    else
        puts("File closed");

    return 0;
}
```

I specify the `mode` argument as `0666`, which should grant read,write access to everyone. However, an `ls -l` shows

`-rw-r--r-- 1 kmehta users    0 2012-01-29 16:29 test.out`

As you can see, write permissions are only granted to the owner of the file. I do not know why everyone else is not granted permissions correctly. `chmod a+w test.out` sets the permissions correctly though.

Code compiled as `gcc -Wall test.c`

Specs: gcc v 4.5.0 on Opensuse 11.3 64 bit

Comment: Did you try using constants for flags, e.g. S_IRUSR, S_IRGRP, etc.?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Using constants didnt help. It was a umask issue, using fchmod after file open now as shown in the answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `mode` argument to `open` specifies the *maximum* allowed permissions. The `umask` setting is then applied to further restrict the permissions.

If you need to make the permissions be 0666 specifically you will need to use `fchmod` on the file handle after the open succeeds or use `umask` to set the process’ permissions mask before the open.

Comment: +1 Two years later and I stumble upon this answer while doing CS homework. I didn't know that I would have to `fchmod` in order to explicitly set the permissions to `0666`

Answer (score 5):

Executing this code :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
        int fd;
        if((fd = open("new.file",O_CREAT,S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO)) == -1)
        {
                perror("open");
                return 1;
        }
        close(fd);
        return 0;
}
```

on my Linux box, where `umask` returns `0022`, gives me a file with the following attributes :

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 daniel daniel    0 Jan 29 23:46 new.file`

So, as you can see, the umask masks out the write bits in my case. It looks like it's the same on your system, too.