# Setting permissions for open() system call in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

I am trying to create a file which will have read, write, execute permissions for user group and others, but this is not happening.

I tried the following command

```
fd = open("file1",O_CREAT| O_WRONLY, 0777);
```

the permissions that this gives is

```
rwx-xr-r-x
```

I want

```
rwxrwxrwx
```

I tried tinkering with other modes like

```
fd2 = open ("file2",O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644 );
```

and they gave the right permissions

```
rw-r--r--
```

where am I going wrong ?

My Code

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int fd;
    fd = open("file1",O_CREAT| O_WRONLY, 0777); 
    int fd2;
    fd2 = open ("file2",O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644 );


}
```

Comment: Check out http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html for the available modes for the O_CREAT flag and use a bit-wise or to select multiple of them.

Comment: Read up on [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) - it controls what file permissions a process can set.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the linked answer does not attempt to show any code that manipulates to umask so the OP can create a file that actually have permission bits of 0777

Comment: @nos well, duplicate of this one by Jonathan

Comment: @nos : I disagree. [open() not setting file permissions correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057419/open-not-setting-file-permissions-correctly) is an exact duplicate (except for `0666` vs. `0777` which is irrelevant to the issue). The same problem with the same solution. If you can provide a better answer, then it can be added to the other question, and this one should still be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Processess have an inheritable `mode_t`-typed property called umask which you can set with the umask call.
When you create a filesystem item with specified permissions `P`, the resulting permissions are `P &~ the_umask`.

Example:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
mode_t getumask(void)
{
    mode_t m = umask(0);
    umask(m);
    return m;

}
int main(void){
    unlink("file1");
    unlink("file2");

    int fd;
    mode_t cur_umask = getumask();
    printf("cur_umask=%#o\n", cur_umask);
    mode_t given_mode=0777;
    if(0>(fd = open("file1",O_CREAT| O_WRONLY, given_mode))) return perror("open"),1;

    struct stat sb;
    if(0>fstat(fd,&sb)) return perror("fstat"),1;
    close(fd);
    printf("given_mode=%#o mode=%#o expected_mode=%#o\n", given_mode, 0777&sb.st_mode, given_mode&~cur_umask);


    //Without cur_umask
    int r=0;
    mode_t oldumask = umask(0);
    given_mode=0777;
    if(0>(fd = open("file2",O_CREAT| O_WRONLY, given_mode))) return perror("open"),1;
    if(0>fstat(fd,&sb)) return perror("fstat"),1;
    printf("given_mode=%#o mode=%#o expected_mode=%#o\n", given_mode, 0777&sb.st_mode, given_mode);

    out:umask(oldumask);
    return r;
}
```

Possible example output:

```
cur_umask=027
given_mode=0777 mode=0750 expected_mode=0750
given_mode=0777 mode=0777 expected_mode=0777
```

Usually, umask is set with the `umask` shell builtin in one of your loggin-session startup scripts (e.g., `/etc/profile`) and is then inherited to descendant processes.

If you want your C process to create filesystem items with permissions exactly as specified, you need to zero your umask before creating your items. Keep in mind that if you intend to exec after the umask change you might want to restore the old value before you exec.